# SQL Server won't create trigger on table I can query

Tags: sql-server, triggers

The command:

```
select * from dbo.hmg_cahplots
```

returns 9250 rows. However, when I try to create a trigger, it fails with:

> Msg 8197, Level 16, State 6, Procedure LotUpdateTrigger_tdp, Line 1
>   The object 'dbo.hmg_cahplots' does not exist or is invalid for this
>   operation.

Trigger code is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.LotUpdateTrigger_tdp ON dbo.hmg_cahplots FOR UPDATE, INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    update lot
    set lot.hmg_planmodelname = model.hmg_modelname, lot.hmg_thermslotincentive = model.hmg_thermsincentive,
        lot.hmg_thermslotincentive_base = model.hmg_thermsincentive_base, lot.hmg_kwlotincentive = model.hmg_kwincentive
    from hmg_cahplots as lot inner join i
            on lot.hmg_cahplotsid = i.hmg_cahplotsid
         inner join hmg_pgecahp as proj 
            on proj.hmg_pgecahpid = lot.hmg_pgecahplots
         left outer join hmg_pgecahpmodels as model 
            on model.hmg_pgecahpmodelsid = lot.hmg_cahpplanstolotsid
            and model.hmg_pgecahpplansid = lot.hmg_pgecahplots         
END
```

I doubt this is very hard to solve. I assume I need to specify a namespace or something. However, I'm new to SQL Server and I don't have any idea how to start on this.

Thanks -- Tim

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Are you sure you are located in correct database, not master?
2. Are you sure your permissions are fine?
3. Are you sure this is a table, not a view?

Comment: I asked our admin to check #2. I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio Express. I'll check the docs and try to figure out how I know if I'm in the correct database, not master. Is there a schema table I can query to see if this is a table or a view?

Comment: Ok...it looks like I'm trying to put a Trigger on a view. The DB diagram I was given is wrong...that explains the mystery. Thanks for the help sorting it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that this table exists and you are trying to create trigger in the same database, then remove coma just before `from` and after `lot.hmg_kwlotincentive = model.hmg_kwincentive,`.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

Triggers are mostly Schema-locked.

You are using more than one.

use the same schema and ADD:

-- AT start add the code

```
USE [DATABASE] --switch with database name
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

--At the END add 
END
GO
```